# Tool to show summarized cpu usage per user

Tags: linux, monitoring, sar

I once saw report that contained information, that within given time frame, total number of x cpu minutes, were used, and this was: - afterwards was list of uids (or usernames), and total number of cpu minutes used by all programs that this user ran in given time frame.

I thought that the program is/was sar, but I can't find any option to do it.

Any hint what program shows such reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking of `sa` rather than `sar`. Take a look at GNU's [process accounting](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/) site.

[Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/html_chapter/accounting.html)